# Randomize order of quiz/flashcards in jquery

Tags: jquery, random, jquery-selectors

I have the following problem
I have a code of a flashcard quiz, but I need it shuffle the order.
I think the best solution is changing something within the next button function.
Here is the code of the function:

```
C.prototype.next = function () {
var that = this;
var $next = this.$current.next();
if (!$next.length) {
  return;
}

setTimeout(function () {
  that.setCurrent($next, 'h5p-previous');

  if (!that.$current.next().length) {
    that.$nextButton.addClass('h5p-hidden');
  }
  that.$prevButton.removeClass('h5p-hidden');
  that.setProgress();
}, 10);
};
```

So what I need to change to pick it a random next question. The important thing is that such a quiz has many questions and it isn't good if a questions gets showed again, so a simple randomize wouldn't work. I tried to solve it with an array and picking one random element and deleting it in a for loop, but I don't do jquery thats the problem. So hoping for your help.

If I had wrote the code I could do that on myself but this way I don't unetrstand much. I also contacted the owner of the code, but the code is old and he doesn't answer, I suppose he isn't active there anymore.

If its not doable within the next button function I can post the complete code.
Thanks in advance. 
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oL978pfa/ can't give you the html code, because it's installed in joomla but here a link http://kanjilearn.net/index.php/n5

Comment: You could add a feature request to [H5P.Flashcards](https://github.com/h5p/h5p-flashcards/issues). There might be more of us  wanting this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Use your random function to generate a permutation rather than selecting random elements.

In a for loop over all elements, swap the current element with a random other element from the array.
And if you need only 10 out of 40 questions, you can just take the first 10 elements.

As far as I know that is just as random as your random function.

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gncuvrsx/

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

var things = [
    "some string", [1, 2, 3], -5, {
    foo: 'bar'
},
3.1415, 42];

alert(things);

var random = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(things));

var L = random.length;

for (var i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    var j = randomIntFromInterval(0, L - 1);
    var b = random[j];
    random[j] = random[i];
    random[i] = b;
}
alert(random);
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but writing a code to pick a random element wasn't the problem. Maybe I didn't explain it very well. The problem is that I don't know where to "install" the random picker in the code.

Comment: Probably I've been too lazy and only read the keywords.
But I'd separate the concerns of picking the next item and randomizing the order of the questions.
So I'd find an earlier place in code to do the randomization.
You don't have to modify code that you don't control.